# log4net logs message into all appenderes (/all files)

Tags: c#, log4net

I am having issues with how log4net manages appenders, and the messages to these appenders.

When I log 1 message to 1 logger (which corresponds to 1 appender), still the message ends up in ALL log files (thus the message seems to go to ALL appenders)

What am I doing wrong?!

I managed to reproduce my problem in a unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        var patternLayout = new PatternLayout
        {
            ConversionPattern = "%date %level %logger - %message%newline" //CreateLayoutPattern(appenderConfiguration.Layout),
        };
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        hierarchy.Configured = true;
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var logFile = Path.Combine(_testLogFolder, $"SomeLog_Test{i}.csv");

            var roller = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                Name = $"Test{i}",
                AppendToFile = true,
                File = logFile,
                CountDirection = 1,
                Layout = patternLayout,
                ImmediateFlush = true,
                // MaxSizeRollBackups is set to max int, software will have an independent mechanism in place (reaper) to clean up old files
                MaxSizeRollBackups = int.MaxValue,
                MaximumFileSize = "1MB",
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
                StaticLogFileName = false,
                PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true,
                Threshold = Level.All
            };

            roller.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);
        }

        // A
        LogManager.GetLogger("Test1").Info("Whatever");

        // Now the ALL of the log files contain the message "Whatever", why?!?! I only logged to 'Test1'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is default behavior (which makes sense when I think about it a little longer :)).

What I need is achievable. Instead of adding all appenders to the `hierarchy.Root.AddAppender` I had to create the logger for each appender name, and then add the roller to that logger. E.g:

```
var logger = hierarchy.GetLogger("Test1", hierarchy.LoggerFactory);

logger.AddAppender(roller);
logger.Level = Level.All;
logger.Additivity = false;
```

And remove :

```
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);
```